# How to resolve Strange behavior in android app

Tags: android, scroll, android-10.0

In my App I experienced a strange behavior. When I use a `TextView` in a `ScrollView` and try then (when the keyboard is open) to scroll the top half of the screen scrolls the bottom half keeps the content. All content is in the ScrollView. It only appears on emulators/devices with a sdk version 29

Even in my minified [example](https://github.com/efinder2/ScrollCrazy) the bug occurs, when `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"` is used. when stateHidden|adjustResize is used, it behaved as expected. In the basic app it also happens with adjustResize.

What cause this strange behavior and how to get rid of it?